# Check the documents and data of an app: STACK-LOGS?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory

After spending a day of working on my app, i realized that the storage it was taking was 1.17 GB. The actual app size is 57.5 MB, while documents & data is taking up 1.11 GB. How can I check what is in my apps document & data?

UPDATE: I downloaded the container by going to Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Click on the app -> Download container.

Then i went inside the containers contents, and I saw all these "stack-logs" that were holding 11-23 MB each, and there was a bunch of them. Anyone know what "stack-logs" are?

Note: My app uses Firebase Database & Storage as a backend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue and literally JUST fixed it. The stack logs save the function call stack for all the allocations created by the app. 
To disable them:
go to your scheme (at the top directly to the left of the simulators), click edit scheme
In "Run", in the diagnostics tab, uncheck the box that says, "Loggin - Malloc Stack"

Comment: Thank you @christian sarcoma ....I was scratching my head from two days as app size kept increasing & even instruments was not able to create that much app size..On the positive end though I have fixed couple of memory leaks in my app as I though they are the main culprit....

Comment: how do i give an answer 1000 upvotes? you're a legend :)

i just spent 3 days trying to debug this issue in Instruments and would have never figured this out. it's crazy that stack log files can get so big.